# progress bar to work with php mysql values

Tags: php, mysql, progress-bar

i have a question in regards to displaying a visual bar comparing mysql values.

i have the following two scripts :

```
<?php
require_once("inc/common.inc.php");

session_start(); 

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = $user[id] LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print $db_field['actual value'] . "<BR>";
}

?>
```

and

```
<?php
require_once("inc/common.inc.php");

session_start(); 

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = $user[id] LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print $db_field['max value'] . "<BR>";
}

?>
```

these two queries show me the actual value and the max value of my user's health.

as of now im printing both values next to each other like 95/100.

i would like to display the above in form of a progress bar according to max and actual.

Any ideas or sugestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
the below answer doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

For e.g.

```
<?php 
$percent = intval($actual_value*100/$max_value);
?>

<div style="width: 200px; background-color: green;">
<span style="width: <?php echo $percent;?>%; background-color: red;"></span>
</div>
```

`$max_value` should be greater than zero of course :)

Comment: so i would do ......   `<?require_once("inc/common.inc.php");

session_start(); 

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = $user[id] LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

$percent = intval($shields*100/$max_shields);
?><div style="width: 200px; background-color: green;">
<span style="width: <?php echo $percent;?>%; background-color: red;"></span>
</div>`

Comment: First, if you select only one user, then you no need in cycles

Answer (score 0):

you could go with a JS progress bar. Assign one value to each progress bar, animate and this should do the trick

Comment: i have searched all over but all i can get my hands is upload progress bars.